# Enhanced eCommerce wrong data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing Enhanced eCommerce with GTM and the measure purchase data is wrong and so many orders are not collected.

The process I've had is I implemented the code but I don't know if I have to set any tags on tag manager because I'm already gathering data, it's just not accurate.

Here is an example code:

> ecommerce:
> purchase:
> actionField:
> affiliation: "Online Store"
> coupon: ""
> id: "69527"
> revenue: "37000"
> shipping: "8000"
> tax: "2394.5"
> products: Array(1)
> 0:
> brand: "MTR"
> category: "Hair color"
> id: "8202"
> name: "Hair color 2"
> price: "29000"
> quantity: "1"

Do I have to make tags in tag manager to make it more accurate?
Here is my website: [SnappMarket](https://snapp.market/)

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on problems on the website or on a failure to return to the order confirmation page after payment.

5% less orders are physiological, higher numbers indicate a problem on the website or in the tracking.